# Async requests fail periodically without errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, async.js

I am trying to build an appointment booking system natively on iOS and the last step involves an Async to an api that checks through the already existing appointments for overlaps in time, if it doesn't it makes the booking. if not it updates the appointment object saying the booking could not be made. However whenever I make a request from app sometimes it works sometime it just makes the response and nothing happens. I deployed the nodejs to Heroku. The api is built with Nodejs while the database is with Firebase. 
Disclaimer: Novice at Nodejs

Nodejs code

```
function handleAsyncFunctionCall(){
var starCountRefasync = firebase.database().ref('bookings').child(barberShopID);
starCountRefasync.on('value', function(snapshotss){
    var dicCollection = snapshotss.val();
    async.each(dicCollection, function(file, callback) {
    console.log('Processing file');
    var currentTime = momenttz.tz(bookingTimeZone);
    selectStartConv = momenttz.tz(selectStart, 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZ', bookingLocal, bookingTimeZone);
    var selectStartConvVerify = momenttz.tz(selectStart, 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZ', bookingLocal, bookingTimeZone).isValid();
    selectEndConv = momenttz.tz(selectEnd, 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZ', bookingLocal, bookingTimeZone);
    var selectEndConvVerify = momenttz.tz(selectEnd, 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZ', bookingLocal, bookingTimeZone).isValid();

    if (selectStartConvVerify == true && selectEndConvVerify == true) {
            var startTim = momenttz.tz(file.bookingStartTime, 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZ', file.local, file.timezone);
            var startTimVerify = momenttz.tz(file.bookingStartTime, 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZ', file.local, file.timezone).isValid();
            var endTim = momenttz.tz(file.bookingEndTime, 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZ', file.local, file.timezone);
            var endTimVerify = momenttz.tz(file.bookingEndTime, 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZ', file.local, file.timezone).isValid();


            if (isDateClashing == false) {
                if(startTimVerify == true && endTimVerify == true){
                    console.log('startTime: ',startTim.toString(), 'currentTime: ',currentTime.toString());
                    if(startTim.isAfter(currentTime)){
                        console.log('red mod');
                        console.log('red shoneville');
                        if (selectStartConv.isBefore(startTim)) {
                            console.log('A is earlier than B');
                            if (selectEndConv.isBefore(startTim)) {
                                console.log('dates dont clash', startTim);
                                isDateClashing = false;

                            }else {
                                console.log('Dates clash');
                                isDateClashing = true;

                            }
                        } else if (selectStartConv.isAfter(startTim) ) {
                            console.log('A is later than B');
                            if (selectStartConv.isAfter(endTim)) {
                                console.log('dates dont clash');
                                isDateClashing = false;
                            }else {
                                console.log('Dates clash');
                                isDateClashing = true;
                            }
                        } else if (selectStartConv.isSame(startTim)){
                            console.log('A is equal to B');
                            console.log('Dates clash');
                            isDateClashing = true;
                        } else {
                            console.log('problem lock');
                            isDateClashing = true;
                        }
                    }else {
                        console.log('why me');
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    callback();
}, function() {
    counter.push(1);

    if (counter.length == 1){
        console.log('money tress is a bitch');
        postDataBasedOnAction();
    }
});
});
```

}

```
function postDataBasedOnAction(){
async.series([
function(callback) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (isDateClashing === true){
        var refToPostDatall = firebase.database().ref('bookings').child(barberShopID);
        var refToBookingStartEndTimell = refToPostDatall.child(bookingID);

        refToBookingStartEndTimell.update({
            'severDidNotMakeBooking': 'YES'

        });

    }else {
        var refToPostData = firebase.database().ref('bookings').child(barberShopID);
        var refToBookingStartEndTime = refToPostData.child(bookingID);

        refToBookingStartEndTime.update({
            'bookingStartTime' : selectStart,
            'bookingEndTime': selectEnd,
            'severDidNotMakeBooking': 'NO'
        });
    }

    callback(null, 'posted');
},
function(callback) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
            user.delete().then(function() {
              firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
                }).catch(function(error) {
                  console.log('Sign out failed', error);
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
            });
        }
    callback(null, 'signed out');
}
```

],

```
function(err, results) {
console.log(err);
if (err == null){
    console.log('there was no error');
    counter = [];
}
```

});
}

Comment: well, I can see you call `callback(null, 'signed out');` before you actually sign out, because, you know, asynchronous code is asynchronous

Comment: you're doing the same thing with `callback(null, 'posted');` - calling that synchronously ignoring the (possibly) asynchronous nature of the code before it - i.e. is `refToBookingStartEndTime.update` asynchronous?

Comment: asynchronous code remains asynchronous - you call callback onde asynchronous code completes ...

Comment: I see the problem, am making the call before it finishes the task. Am quite new to node.js. Can you give me any pointers to make it better.

Comment: yes, you call callback once asynchronous code completes